# foreach no match -C shell script

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, foreach

I’m trying to write my first script to search for a given pattern in text file named test.  Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/csh
 echo -n "enter pattern: "
  set pattern = $<
    foreach word (`cat test`)
         echo $word | egrep $pattern
    end
```

When I try to run it I get the message foreach: No match found. I suspect the problem is caused by (`cat test`). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It works for me as-is (without added whitespace).

Comment: So maybe it is a problem with C shell.

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be C shell...? you can learn to search files using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{
 printf "Enter Pattern: "
 getline pattern < "-"
}
$0 ~ pattern{
    print 
}
' myfile
```

Comment: ok problme solved. There must be white space after opening and before closing brackets.

Answer (score 1):

@Pat - glad you've fixed it.  Looping over the words in the file and running egrep over each one is a bit of an odd way to do it - I presume you're learning about C shell loops, rather than looking for the most succinct solution.  You could match against the whole file in one go:

```
egrep "\b$pattern\b" test
```

The `\b` makes grep match on a word boundary.

You have my sympathy programming with csh - here's some food for thought: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: Thanks Martin. This is a part of my coursework assignment and unfortunately we have to use C shell. As for the Csh Programming Considered Harmful I had read it already :).